# Real time chart with angular2-highcharts

Tags: angular, real-time, angular2-highcharts

I want to insert real time chart in my angular2 application, I'm using  angular2-highcharts.

```
npm install angular2-highcharts --save
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
  options: Object;
  constructor() {
    this.options = {
      title : { text : 'simple chart' },
      series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2],
      }]
    };
  }

}
```

app.component.html

```
<chart [options]="options"></chart>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {ChartModule} from "angular2-highcharts";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,ChartModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I'm having this error when running my angular2 application :
"No provider for HighchartsStatic!".
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12):

I ran into this exact problem.  [This solution](https://github.com/gevgeny/angular2-highcharts/issues/178) from [matthiaskomarek](https://github.com/matthiaskomarek) did the trick for me:

```
import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-highcharts';
import { HighchartsStatic } from 'angular2-highcharts/dist/HighchartsService';

declare var require: any;
export function highchartsFactory() {
  return require('highcharts');
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
      ChartModule
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  exports: [],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HighchartsStatic,
      useFactory: highchartsFactory
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule
```

I'm not sure why this question was voted down, because it really an issue.  I'm running into the exact same thing here!

The highchart documentation as it stands suggest that `ChartModule.forRoot(require('highcharts')` is all that is required (filling in, of course, the missing `)`in the documentation).  With angular-cli projects, I can never get `require` to work, so `declare var require: any;` usually does the trick. Except here, calling it within the context of `forRoot` seems to result in:

> ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically.
>   Reference to a local (non-exported) symbol 'require'. Consider
>   exporting the symbol (position 18:14 in the original .ts file),
>   resolving symbol AppModule in ... app/app.module.ts

My guess is that [matthiaskomarek](https://github.com/matthiaskomarek)'s workaround avoids this.

Comment: sloved it for me! Thank you very much

Comment: I believe its not working in angular 11. Do you know anything about this ?

Answer (score 9):

You need to use `ChartModule.forRoot()` in your imports:

```ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ChartModule.forRoot(require('highcharts'))  // <-- HERE
  ],
  // ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://github.com/gevgeny/angular2-highcharts)? All the possible syntaxes are clearly explained...

Comment: file systemjs.config.js not found                                                                            ...
map: {
  ...
  'angular2-highcharts': 'node_modules/angular2-highcharts',
  'highcharts': 'node_modules/highcharts',
}
...
packages: {
  ...
  highcharts: {
    main: './highcharts.js',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  'angular2-highcharts': {
    main: './index.js',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  }
}

Comment: if it is easy so what is this error "No provider for HighchartsStatic!".

Comment: Did you write exactly `ChartModule.forRoot(require('highcharts'))`?

Comment: yes but where I can add map:{...} & packages: {...} because systemjs.config.js not found

Comment: Are you sure you're using SystemJS? How did you create your Angular app?

Comment: With CLI ,where I can add map:{...} & packages: {...}

Comment: There's no `systemjs.config.js` file with Angular CLI. If you read the angular2-highcharts documentation, it says "For angular-cli and other Webpack environments, no any additional setup needed". Maybe you should familiarize yourself with Angular and its environment before attempting more complex projects.

Comment: I have add ChartModule.forRoot(require('highcharts')) ,I have this error "Calling function 'ChartModule', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function" ,thanks

Comment: Using this 'forRoot' solution worked for me! using CLI

Comment: This is the correct solution, thanks @AngularChef !

Answer (score 4):

Another workaround if Marc Brazeau's fix doesn't work for you (it didn't for me) is to do the following:

```
import {ChartModule} from 'angular2-highcharts';
import {HighchartsStatic} from 'angular2-highcharts/dist/HighchartsService';
import * as highcharts from 'highcharts';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [ChartModule],
    providers: [
    {
        provide: HighchartsStatic,
        useValue: highcharts
    }],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-highcharts';
import * as something  from 'highcharts';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  AppComponent],
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  FormsModule,
  HttpModule,
  ChartModule.forRoot(something).ngModule
],
providers: [ChartModule.forRoot(something).providers],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Answer (score 3):

**Finally got solution for this , check my** `app.module` **file :**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import 'hammerjs';
import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-highcharts';
import * as highcharts from 'highcharts';
import { HighchartsStatic } from 'angular2-highcharts/dist/HighchartsService';

import { AppRouting } from './app.routing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

declare var require: any;


export function highchartsFactory() {
      const hc = require('highcharts');
      const dd = require('highcharts/modules/drilldown');
      dd(hc);

      return hc;
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AppRouting,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    ChartModule
  ],
  providers: [{
      provide: HighchartsStatic,
      useFactory: highchartsFactory
    }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Only answer I've seen for getting multiple high-charts modules to work. Thanks!

Comment: I think its not working in angular 11.
getting this below error:
No provider for HighchartsStatic!